# CompletableFuture - async task execution is erroneous?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

My problem statement is that I have multiple monitor objects in place, and I have to execute all of them asynchronously and report their status to some external service

- success means if the task executed in 100 milliseconds,
- failure or timeout should be reported for tasks that takes more than 100 milliseconds

Following is my code which executes 10 async tasks out of them 5 get finished quickly and the other 5 take more time. I'm using `timeoutFuture`, a separate thread that times out after 100 milliseconds which is then used to determine whether earlier async task is completed within 100 milliseconds or not.

My expectation is that final 5 success responses and 5 failure responses should display in output, **but every time I run this code, consistently only two successful and 8 failure tasks are being reported.**

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public class TesFutureStuff {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> failAfter(long longValue) {
        final CompletableFuture<T> timeoutFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        scheduler.schedule(() -> {
            final TimeoutException ex = new TimeoutException("Timeout after " + longValue);
            return timeoutFuture.completeExceptionally(ex);
        }, longValue, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return timeoutFuture;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<CustomMonitor> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(e -> new CustomMonitor("hello"+e, e%2==0 ? true : false)).forEach(arr::add);

        arr.forEach(TesFutureStuff::submitTask);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void submitTask(CustomMonitor i) {
        final CompletableFuture<CustomResponse> CustomResponseFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> i.execute()).
                exceptionally(ex -> {
                    System.out.println("help");
                    return new CustomResponse(ex.getMessage() , i.name);
                    });

        CustomResponseFuture
        .acceptEither(failAfter(100l), TesFutureStuff::updateStatus)
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            System.out.println("failure "+throwable.getMessage());
            updateStatus(new CustomResponse(throwable.getMessage() , i.name));
            return null;
        })/*.getNow(null )*/;

    }
    static private void updateStatus(CustomResponse resp) {
        System.out.println(resp+"status reported ");
    }
}
    class CustomResponse {

        String status;
        String testType;
        public CustomResponse( String stat , String testType) {
            status = stat;
            this.testType = testType;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return status.toString() + " " + testType.toString();
        }

    }

    class CustomMonitor{

        String name;
        boolean mTimeOut ;
        public CustomMonitor(String aName , boolean aShouldTimeOut) {
            mTimeOut = aShouldTimeOut;
            name = aName;
        }

        public CustomResponse execute()  {
            CustomResponse CustomResponse = new CustomResponse("success", name);;
            if (mTimeOut) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                CustomResponse = new CustomResponse("fail", name);
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Executing "+name);
            return CustomResponse;
        }
    }
```

## Output:

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2 Executing hello1
success hello1status reported 
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2 Executing hello3
success hello3status reported 
failure java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100 hello0status reported 
failure java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100
failure java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100 hello2status reported 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100 hello4status reported 
failure java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100 hello5status reported 
failure java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100
failure java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100 hello7status reported 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100 hello6status reported 
failure java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100
failure java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100 hello8status reported 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after 100 hello9status reported 
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 Executing hello0
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 Executing hello5
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 Executing hello2
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2 Executing hello4
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 Executing hello7
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 Executing hello9
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 Executing hello6
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2 Executing hello8
```

Comment: Please consider converting your code into a valid [mcve], one that does not require outside libraries or resources, so that we are able to copy, paste, and then compile and run it without modification. It would make answering your question *much* easier.

Comment: When I run your code, I'm getting 5 successes & 5 timeouts. Isn't it how it's supposed to be?

Comment: @PankajSinghal Actually i should get 5 success 5 failures but am getting 2 sucess and 8 timeout /failure exceptions.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I'm getting 5 success 5 failure from running your code.

Comment: @PankajSinghal - Oh , i just edited post to include the output that am getting in my system. Can you please  take a look at it and provide me any pointers ? Thank you

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels   Sry for the inconvenience - i edited the code to remove external dependencies can you please check ? Thank you

Comment: It's working for me.